# Excel: Stop watch format without seconds

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

How to achieve a cell format like 26:30 (meaning 26 hours, 30 minutes), without seconds? Such format is not predefined. There is only 26:30:00 or 26:30,0 in the program settings available.

Comment: Use custom formatting?

Comment: For sure, but how? Already tried with hh:mm, but it is clock time (entering 26:00 changes to 02:00)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the one that is for timespans not for  dates. `[h]:mm` would be the format definition in your case.